# Timezone for cron jobs

Tags: cron, centos5, timezone

We have a VDS running CentOS 5.5 that was created and configured with the EDT timezone. I have replaced `etc/localtime` with a link pointing to the `Australia/Melbourne` (UTC+10) timezone file. Running the `date` command displays the correct date and time.

The problem is that cron jobs are being run as if the server was still using the EDT timezone, even after a reboot. e.g. A job that should have run at 1:01AM just ran at 3:01PM.

What have I missed?

Comment: Do you mean that in crontab -e you have ```01 01 * * * *``` and it actually runs at ```01 15 * * * *```

Comment: Run `date` from cron and see what time zone it shows.

Comment: @Paul, yes that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @Pawel, that test revealed cron is definitely still using EDT. quanta's answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After changing the time zone, restart the crond service is enough, no need to reboot. Don't know why your cron is still using the EDT timezone, but insert a below line before your cron line:

```
TZ=Australia/Melbourne
* * * * * ...
```

and try again.

Comment: This works, although I'd still like to understand why it should even be necessary.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary, but if you change the timezone of your server, you need to restart cron so that it knows of the change.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - after I changed the system's timezone, cron's log entries were in the old timezone, even after restarting crond. Then I noticed that ALL log entries were off - messages, mail, and any other programs using syslog.

```
service rsyslog restart
```

The first thing syslog does is log a message (naturally enough), so I was able to see that it had the correct timestamp. I restarted crond, just to be sure, and its log entries were correct, as well.